# Литература для написания игры "Шашки" на Java

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте =)

Недавно начал изучать Java. Пока только "плетусь" вначале =), дочитывая "Философия Java" Эккеля. Вот в этом семестре взял тему курсового проекта: игра "Шашки". Я полностью не знаком с разработкой визуальных приложений на Java, поэтому решил спросить Вас о лучшем способе реализации "Шашек". Слышал, например, про "внутренний" Swing... Но хватит ли мне его для нормальной реализации? Хочу просто четко понять какие средства мне дадут возможность реализовать простую и приятную, хотя бы для себя, игру, с учетом того, что я новичок, да и времени остается все меньше и меньше =).

Спасибо Вам огромное заранее ;)

Comment: гугли готовый код, сам не осилишь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно литературу посоветовать не могу, т.к на Java еще не писал, но зато могу дать пару советов. Вы уже знакомы с классами, судя по вашим вопросам, и написание визуальной программы будет намного легче. Не знаю какие компоненты есть в Java, но на Delphi/C# я бы сделал через 1 компонент Image и image list. После хода изображение будет обновляться из list + добавляться перегородки для клеток. По-моему вполне прилично.

Вариант посложнее: XNA/OpenGl загрузили текстуры поля, фишек и ограждений. Заранее расставили для них местщ и с анимацией( по +-2 пикселя передвигаем по X,Y). Выйдет вообще шикарно).

Интелект, к сожалению, никогда не делал, но сделал бы 3 уровня сложности и чем выше тем меньше будет шанс ошибиться. Например 40%,20%,5% соответственно.

P.S была идея с одногруппником написать морской бой 2 версии, каждый пишет свой интеллект и реализовать сервер, который будет кидать каждой версии исходные данные и высылать соответственно другой стороне уже новые исходные данные). Как бы кто умнее напишет. Быть может вам будет это интересно и тоже захотите написать.

Answer (score 1):

Относительно gui попробуй gtk+. Java c ней хорошо дружит. Что касается "мозга" игры, почитай дискретную математику, в частности минимаксный алгоритм. Поищи его применение к играм. Шашки часто в качестве примера приводят

Comment: Спасибо, Паша. Надеюсь, поможешь его на лекции какой-нить реализовать :D